# What is wrong with the query's syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, web-development-server

Here is the text of my query that has a syntax error.

```
select cc, sum(a.hours),b.labcost
from labour a,othshop b
where lab_cd='hs' and a.mon=03 and a.yr=2010
group by a.cc
HAVING a.cc=b.occ AND b.mon=03 and b.yr=2010;
```

All the tables exist. What is wrong with the text of this query?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in `having`, just:

```
select a.cc, sum(a.hours),b.labcost
from labour a,othshop b
where lab_cd='hs' and a.mon=03 and a.yr=2010
and a.cc=b.occ AND b.mon=03 and b.yr=2010
group by a.cc, b.labcost
```

note that `b.labcost` was added to the `GROUP BY`. Otherwise, you'll need to perform an aggregation on it, such as `avg(b.labcost)`

Comment: Thanks. but i need to group only by a.cc This program was made in a DBASE system I am trying to convert it into a mysql and php based database.

Comment: then as I suggested- try to figure out how to convert multiple ``b.labcost`` into a single line per ``a.cc``. The obvious candidates are ``avg``, ``sum`` or ``coalesce``